# password form which will be called in other forms to authenticate other form access in c#

Tags: c#, forms, password-protection

I previously made a string password which worked, however cannot be used in other forms to authenticate. So I created a local server database table which contained the password. Then I called this table and password into the GetPass form which is the form used to authenticate access to other forms. However, due to limited knowledge, I'm struggling to make this happen, any tips or examples will be much appreciated. ( within the code methods from the string password attempt are still visible)

```
namespace BooyaaBrowser
{
    public partial class GetPass : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BooyaaBrowser;Integrated Security=True");

        private TextBox PasstextBox;
        private Button btn_confirm;
        private Label EnterPass;
        private string refPassword;



        public GetPass(string Password)
        {


                InitializeComponent();
                refPassword = Password;

            } 



        private void btn_confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                   con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from password where password =('" + PasstextBox.Text + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
           // string password = PasstextBox.Text;
            //if (password.CompareTo(refPassword) == 0)
           // {
           //     this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
           // this.Close();
```

Comment: Are yóu just stuck continuing? Or is there an error in the code?

Comment: @IanH. I'm stuck and have no idea how to carry on so it's a global password authentication forms within the name space for other forms